# MOSFET driver IR2301S

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I am trying to implement a brushless motor driver using an [IR2301S](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2301(S)-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c97bb216dc) driver. I started with testing the driver without MOSFETs. Here is schematic:

[image]

In the datasheet of the IR2301S is this picture:

[image]
If I understood correctly, I should see oscillating on LO if there is an oscillating signal on LIN and unconnected HIN, VS. I got it. But when I send an oscillating signal on HIN while LIN and VS are unconnected I don't see oscillating on HO; there is stable 6 V on HO. Input signal amplitude is 3.3 V. I've tried to change VCC up to 12 V, change the capacity of C1 and C4 from 1 μF to 100 μF without luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's a *floating* high-side driver. As Andy shows in his answer, if you just leave Vs floating you'll never see any output on Ho.

Comment: The high side portion of the circuitry in the driver IC is powered by the charge stored in the capacitor C2. In normal operation, where the gate driver controls a MOSFET half bridge, turning the low side transistor on pulls VS low, charging C2 through the diode D1. If you keep the low side transistor off for an extended time, the voltage at VS is likely higher than VCC, causing C2 to slowly discharge and the high side to turn off, even when HIN is high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the block diagram: -

[image]

Without connecting Vs to 0V and Vb to +V you will see nothing on HO